# Prove Matching of Size K

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, matching-theory

The problem is as follows: Given a graph with n vertices, each having degree >= 2k, prove that a matching of size >= k exists. (n > 2k > 0)

My initial approach has been that if we can just find a path within the graph of length 2k, then simply alternating the edges in that path would result in a matching of size k. But now I'm not sure how to prove that such a path of length 2k exists.

Comment: Your posts will look better and be easier to read if you format them with [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Suppose $(v_1, \ldots, v_m)$ is a path.  If $v_m$ has degree $\ge m$, there is some edge $(v_m, v_{m+1})$ so $(v_1, \ldots, v_{m+1})$ is a path.

Comment: I've thought about doing it this way but I'm not quite sure when to "stop adding" on vertices. I thought that at some point since every vertex has degree >= 2k the path will become a cycle?

Comment: You're given that the degree $\ge 2k$, so you can stop when $m=2k$, obtaining a path of $2k+1$ distinct vertices.  If the path $(v_1, \ldots, v_{2k+1})$ can't be extended, the vertices $v_i$ for $1 \le i \le 2k$ must all be adjacent to $v_{2k+1}$, so $(v_1, \ldots, v_{2k+1})$ is also a cycle.  But all you've been asked for is a matching of size $\ge k$.

Answer (score 0):

Use induction. If you pick any edge $vw$, then deleting $v$ and $w$ from $G$ produces a graph with minimum degree $2k-2$.